# Sending data to 2 servers at once

Tags: webserver, game-development

Lets say I have a server for broadcasting a character's position in an online game and a server for voice chatting with a group of players in the same game. Would the client be able to send data to both servers? Would they connect? Would this work? Would it be practical?

Comment: Yes, if they use different IP ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: That's actually pretty common. Your *browser* does it all the time, connecting to different servers using different protocols (HTTP and HTTPS, at least), for example. Most mail clients support an even wider range of protocols (POP3, IMAP, SMTP, sometimes NNTP and encrypted variants thereof) and can easily handle multiple servers in parallel. A networked game client works, on the network protocol level, *exactly* like those, so there's nothing out-of-ordinary nor impractical in doing so.